# Increment an Int every time function is called?

Tags: elm

In Elm is there any way I can create a past-dependent function that returns an incremented Int every time it is called? Signal.foldp is almost there, but I can't find a signal to use!

It could be that what I am trying to do is nonsensical, but the basic scenario is I am making a datagrid. I (apparently, it's really hard to figure out how to do this) need every cell to have a unique ID in elm, but not all cells may be persisted to the storage yet. So I would like all "empty" cells to automatically get different negative IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was to abandon this idea entirely. Cells are now identified by their row and column, generated by nested indexedMap calls in the view function. I decided to pass the row and column to the Cell view function as arguments, and not store them in the Cell model, because only the parent Grid really cares about what row and column a cell is.

I actually had to create a 2D Array library as a wrapper for Array (Array a), because it was necessary to be able to get and set individual cells without mapping over the entire grid.

Comment: Is there anything that you don't like about my [matrix](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/sindikat/elm-matrix/1.2.0/Matrix) library? Feel absolutely free to propose any missing features on GitHub [issues](https://github.com/sindikat/elm-matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Side-effects have to be explicit in Elm.

If you want a function to have an effect, that function needs to return a Task (or Effect) and that task needs to be sent to a port for execution.

The Elm Architecture Tutorial example 6 through 8 provide examples of how to have functions that return Effects (Effects are just a nice interface to Tasks).

That being said, if your grid is fixed from the beginning you might not need foldp at all. You might be able to get by with a simple foldl from List.

Here is a small example to show that.

```
import Html exposing (..) 


type alias Data = List (Int, Int, Bool)

type alias ID = Int

type alias TaggedData = List (ID, (Int, Int, Bool)) 

data : Data 
data = [ (0,0, True), (0,1, False)
       , (1,0, True), (1,1, False)]



toTaggedData : Data -> TaggedData
toTaggedData d =
  let 
    f (x, y, v) (pos, neg, acc) = 
      if v 
      then ((pos+1), neg, (pos, (x, y, v))::acc)
      else (pos, (neg-1), (neg, (x, y, v))::acc)
    (max, min, list) = List.foldl f (1, -1, []) d
  in 
   List.reverse list

main = text <| toString <| toTaggedData data
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty interesting. I haven't learned how to use Tasks and Effects yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky: you want the function to secretly hold on to some state, and mutate it every time you call that function. You can't really do this in Elm: secret mutability is explicitly disallowed. You would need to do something in native land.

If you are generating a datagrid, does each cell have a row/column index? Could you use those to generate the identifier?

A little more detail on what you're trying to do might help if that suggestion doesn't help :-)

Comment: That is actually how I eventually solved it, many headaches later. The cell view function takes a row and column argument, and the cell data is implemented as Array (Array Cell) and I had to write a whole 2D array library to make working with this not painful.

Answer (score 1):

@grumpyjames' idea is good.  Here are two more:

1. If you want an application-wide sequence counter, you could have a 'highest (or lowest) ID so far' variable in your model, and use that as the argument in a function to generate the next ID;
2. If each ID just needs to be unique, but you don't require them to be sequential, you could use a random number generator and give each cell a UUID.  Then you don't need to worry about state (although, depending on how Elm does random number generation, you might need to hold on to the seed).

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not actual anymore but if you create a module for the data grid cells you could add a counter to the model and increment it every time update is called:

```
type alias Model =
  { content : String
  , counter : Int
  }

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
    { model | 
    content = newContent
    , counter = model.counter + 1
    }
```

Now in Elm 0.17 Signals are gone so I guess it's much easier now fwiw